# NodeJS + JSON + jQuery: send JSON-object form Node-backend to jQuery-frontend

Tags: jquery, json, node.js, post, ejs

I'm trying to send JSON-object form MongoDB to page with ejs template engine. Here's the response form my DB (a JSON-object):

```
"suppliers": [
    {
        "lastname": "lastname1",
        "firstname": "firstname1",
        "middlename": "middlename1",
        "mobtel": "mobtel1",
        "worktel": "worktel1",
        "email": "email1"
    },
    {
        "lastname": "lastname2",
        "firstname": "firstname2",
        "middlename": "middlename2",
        "mobtel": "mobtel2",
        "worktel": "worktel2",
        "email": "email2"
    }
]
```

As I get i from DB as an object, I have to stringify it to str to send as a var for EJS Template engine:

```
var myJSONText = JSON.stringify(doc.suppliers);
profile["suppliers"] =myJSONText;
...
res.render('profile.ejs',{profile:profile});
```

On front-end I get a plain string with json-data.
I parse it via jQuery to an object:

```
var jsonObject = jQuery.parseJSON('<%= profile.suppliers %>');
for (var i=0; i<jsonObject.length; i++){
    //trying to show field 'name' for every supplier
    alert(jsonObject[i]['lastname']);
}
```

...and it doesnt work, but should to alert me twice. I've tried to inspect a plain-text JSON-string, comming to front-end, and found out such symbols:

```
[{&quot;lastname&quot;: &quot; ...
```

It seems that `jQuery.parseJSON` is not able to create a valid object from such string. What I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

**UPDATE: Well, I've turned my code into:**

NodeJS code:

```
profile["suppliers"] =doc.suppliers;
res.render('profile.ejs', { profile:profile });
```

jQuery code:

```
for (var i=0; i<'<%= profile.suppliers %>'.length; i++){
//trying to show field 'name' for every supplier
alert('<%= profile.suppliers %>'[i]['lastname']);
}
```

and it gives me never-ending loop of undefined alerts.

**UPDATE 2: I've updated my source code, so:**

NodeJS:

```
var myJSONText = JSON.stringify(doc.suppliers);
profile["suppliers"] =myJSONText;
res.render('profile.ejs',{profile:profile});
```

Client:

```
var jsonObject = <%- profile.suppliers %>;
$.each(jsonObject, function(item) {
    alert(item.lastname);
});
```

Generated source code:

```
var jsonObject = [{"lastname":"lastname1","firstname":"firstname1","middlename":"middlename1","mobtel":"mobtel1","worktel":"worktel1","email":"email1"},{"lastname":"lastname2","firstname":"firstname2","middlename":"middlename2","mobtel":"mobtel2","worktel":"worktel2","email":"email2"}];
```

Seems to be ok, but still gives me undefined alerts. Hoever, it alerts **only twice**, that means that it parses JSON correctly and just cannot get access to lastname property?

Comment: Why do you have to stringify your JSON in the first place? EJS should handle the object fine.

Comment: I've updated original post. Please, take a look.

Comment: @WesJohnson: It needs to be stringified so that it can be inserted into the javascript file. However, it does not need to be parsed at the other end.

Comment: This part of your code is broken: `i<'<%= profile.suppliers %>'.length`. You're iterating over the length of a string, not an array of objects.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you correctly diagnosed, `&quot;`s are being inserted into your JSON. This renders it invalid, preventing it being decoded.

This is because in [ejs](https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs/blob/master/Readme.md), `<%= ... %>` does html output escaping, hence the `&quot;`. You need to use `<%- profile.suppliers %>` to avoid this.

There's no need to use `JSON.parse` on the client: JSON is already valid javascript code, so can be inserted straight into the code, rather than being stored as a string literal.

```
var jsonObject = <%- profile.suppliers %>;
$.each(jsonObject, function() {
    alert(this.lastname);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try your solution if Wes' and Terry's variant without stringifying object to plain text will not work

Comment: Thanks, I got it, however it doesn't work. If I use your code directly, script doesn't work. If I use quotes (var jsonObject = '<%- profile.suppliers %>';), it still gives me an never-ending loop of undefined alerts.

Comment: Let me note, that I dont stringify object on backend-side now

Comment: Oh, I've just saw your comment that I must stringify JSON-object.

Comment: @IlyaRusanen: Does it work now then? Have a look at the source code it generates if it doesn't.

Comment: Not completely, but we are very close :) I've updated my post.

Comment: @IlyaRusanen: Looks like you copied my code mid update. I had a memory failure WRT ho `jQuery.each` works. Try again.

Answer (score 0):

As Wes is eluding to, I think you're doing unnecessary stringifying/parsing.

Try this:

```
var suppliers = // your JSON source

$(suppliers).each(function() {
   alert(this.lastname);
});
```

Comment: I've tried var suppliers = '<%= profile.suppliers %>';
$(suppliers).each(function() {
alert(this.lastname);
}); but no luck :(

Comment: I'm not familiar with ejs, but if Eric's suggestion works I would expect the code I posted to parse it correctly.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see Eric's comment about the necessity of stringifying my object.